# Google Sheets Script Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 7, file "Rando")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to essentially print a randomly generated number in one cell to another cell. I wrote this simple thing - but I keep getting the TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 7, file "Rando")- error. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help :D

```
function random() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var row = 3;
  var col = 26;
  var col2 = 27;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ownership of Businesses");
  var base = sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue();

  sheet.getRange(row,col2).setValue(base)

}
```

Comment: sheet is `null`, check it exists. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)

Comment: ugh - immediately deleting this post... so embarrassing. Yea, the sheet was not named tha!!! :(